# jQuery - toggle only next element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'd like to toggle just the next element (and not others) with jQuery: I'll explain myself with examples.

This is the HTML:

```
<article id="post-60" class="post-60 page type-page status-publish hentry">
    <header class="entry-header">
        <h1 class="entry-title">Pagine Critiche</h1>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content">
        <p><strong>TITLE 1.1</strong></p>
        <p><strong>TITLE 1.2</strong></p>
        <p><em>Writer writes:</em></p>
        <p>Article #1</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>

        <p><strong>TITLE 2.1</strong></p>
        <p><strong>TITLE 2.2</strong></p>
        <p><em>Writer writes:</em></p>
        <p>Article #2.1</p>
        <p>Article #2.2</p>
        <p>Article #2.3</p>
    </div>
</article>
```

I'd like to click on TITLE 1.1 and show (toggle) ALL that there is between TITLE 1 and TITLE 2 (so everything between the first "strong p" and the second "strong p"); in a few words: I'd like to toggle just the article that refers to that title.

I've tried to write this script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#post-60 p strong").click(function(){
        $("p:not(:has(strong))").toggle(500);
    });
});
```

But it toggles all the "normal" paragraph at the same time; here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpxhkh1r/).
I believe I need the next() selector, but I'm not using it the right way, like I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#post-60 p strong").click(function(){
        $("p:not(:has(strong))").next().toggle(500);
    });
});
```

but it's not working either.

I'd like to solve it without having to edit the HTML markup.

Comment: More likely https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/

Comment: If you can control the HTML you could simply have the content tags as children of the title one and then it would be very easy to toggle them relatively to their parent.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is exactly that I can't control the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't update your markup then apply this JS.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#post-60 p strong").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().next('p').nextUntil( "p:has(strong)").toggle(500);
    });
});
```

Working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xpxhkh1r/3/

It would be much more simpler if you could just rewrite your markup. Here is a example.

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <p><strong>TITLE 1.1</strong></p>
    <div class="item">
        <p><strong>TITLE 1.2</strong></p>
        <p><em>Writer writes:</em></p>
        <p>Article #1</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>

    <p><strong>TITLE 2.1</strong></p>
    <div class="item">
        <p><strong>TITLE 2.2</strong></p>
        <p><em>Writer writes:</em></p>
        <p>Article #2.1</p>
        <p>Article #2.2</p>
        <p>Article #2.3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the JS should look like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#post-60 p strong").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().next('.item').toggle(500);
    });
});
```

See the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xpxhkh1r/1/

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#post-60 p>strong").click(function() {
    var $thisP = $(this).closest("p");
    if ($thisP.next().has("strong").length > 0) { // next P has strong, we are on x.1
      $thisP.next().toggle(500);
      $thisP.next().nextUntil("p:has(strong)").toggle(500);
    } else { // we are on x.2
      $thisP.nextUntil("p:has(strong)").toggle(500);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article id="post-60" class="post-60 page type-page status-publish hentry">
  <header class="entry-header">
    <h1 class="entry-title">Pagine Critiche</h1>
  </header>
  <!-- .entry-header -->

  <div class="entry-content">
    <p><strong>TITLE 1.1</strong>
    </p>
    <p><strong>TITLE 1.2</strong>
    </p>
    <p><em>Writer writes:</em>
    </p>
    <p>Article #1</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>

    <p><strong>TITLE 2.1</strong>
    </p>
    <p><strong>TITLE 2.2</strong>
    </p>
    <p><em>Writer writes:</em>
    </p>
    <p>Article #2.1</p>
    <p>Article #2.2</p>
    <p>Article #2.3</p>
  </div>
</article>
```